# Extracting the last segment on an URI

Tags: php, regex

String # 1:

```
/string/morestring/thename
```

String # 2:

```
/string/morestring/thename/
```

Regex:

```
[^\/]*[\/]*$
```

The above regex matches both last segments...

How can the regex match only the last **word** on both "thename" AND "thename/", with or without final slash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[^\/]+\/?$
```

http://rubular.com/r/TeAEWM0jsd

Comment: Selecting solution since question was regarding regex and not implicitly attached to a particular language or method. All answers solve different problems, very well appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I would just use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

Comment: +1. Would basename work for a URI if PHP is running on Windows though? (since the path separator is \\)

Comment: @Ben According to the manual: `On Windows, both slash (/) and backslash (\\) are used as directory separator character.`

Comment: @jeroen. What about the extension? basename('/test/file.gif') is 'file', not 'file.gif' (AFAIK)

Comment: @Ben No, the extension is included. Perhaps you are looking at the example in the manual where they used the second parameter?

Answer (score 3):

jeroen's basename solution is very good <strike>but might not work on windows, it would also cut out the extension if the URI ends with .something too.</strike>

I'd do this:

```
 $last = array_pop(explode('/',rtrim($s,'/')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
$last = array_pop(preg_split('#/+#', rtrim($s, '/')));
```