# Get last parameter of url in php

Tags: php, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting the last segment on an URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928745/extracting-the-last-segment-on-an-uri)

I want to get the last parameter of the url for eg.

http://www.youtube.com/embed/ADU0QnQ4eDs

I have a full url like above and i want to get only last parameter with the **PHP** which is 
**ADU0QnQ4eDs**

Please help

Comment: `echo basename("http://www.youtube.com/embed/ADU0QnQ4eDs");`

Comment: [please use the search function before asking duplicates. How to get the last segment in the url path has been asked and answered a dozen times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+last+segment+of+url+[php])

Comment: Those "duplicates" are full of the end/explode "help" offered here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this?

```
echo end(explode("/", $url));
```

This will throw an error if strict error reporting is enabled.
To avoid this, split them up like this:

```
$parts = explode("/", $url);
echo end($parts);
```

Comment: -1. Why not just use the **native, intended function**? `basename()`, or even `parse_url()` if you want to get fancy.

Comment: @Truth You are downvoting my anser for not giving the solution you would use? This is what I do and it works - you can use the **native, intended function** if you want to.

Comment: I am downvoting because you reinvent the wheel, implementing a solved solution on your own needlessly.

Comment: basename() is the best optimized solution.

Comment: @Farhan Upvoting other answers are for comments like that.

Comment: @Repox I have already upvoted your answer bro..

Comment: good suggestion

Answer (score 9):

There are functions for that.

```
$url      = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/ADU0QnQ4eDs';
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$basename = pathinfo($url_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

// $basename is "ADU0QnQ4eDs"
```

See http://php.net/parse_url and http://php.net/pathinfo.

Comment: +1 This code speaks when you read it. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pattern here that can be easily scanned:

```
$interestedIn = sscanf($url, 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/%s');
```

Don't make your live more complicated than it needs to be. Technically `substr` would work, too, but this one adds more context.